# Doubts regarding Static Memory and Dynamic Memory (stack and heap)

Tags: c

So i have a couple of questions about the use of memory in a program written in C.

1. If i declare a global variable outside of the main function (without
   the static prefix), this will be stored in the static memory or in
   the stack memory?
2. If i declare a variable with the static prefix inside a function,
   this will be stored in the static memory or in the stack memory?
3. The same as the question 1, but with a const variable outside the
   main function.

Greetings.

Comment: All 3 in static memory.

Comment: Everything on the stack is invalid after the stack frame is popped at the end of a function call - so how could any of these be stack?

Comment: A "google search" tell me that's all static & in the bss segment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss

Comment: @brokenfoot: That's the problem with Google, it looks at words. The .bss can contain global variables, but it doesn't mean that global variables have to be in .bss or even that C requires the presence of .bss

Comment: @Mark: It's no problem if they're popped off when `main` returns.

Comment: @MSaLters: Uninitalized ones in bss.. or data segment in general..

Comment: @brokenfoot: Same thing, if there's a data segment it may contain etc. - doesn't mean that there must be such a segment or that all such vars go there.

Answer (score 0):

All global variables and static variables need to be active as long as the program runs. they are not cleared when a function returns. So they cant be stored on stack.
These are stored on `data segment`. you can read [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/) to know where the variables are stored in memory layout of a program.

Comment: That link gives one possible example, but it's incorrect for all of todays OS'es

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know the answer for your question but then I search for this and the following document pretty much cleared me the memory layout. Go through the examples in given link for better understanding:
[Geeksforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/)

Answer (score 0):

It's unspecified for all three whether they're on the stack, but in each case they'd have to be on the top of the stack, at or above the level where `main` is.

The reason is that all three should hold a value even when the only function on the stack is `main`, but you can't (portably) determine if such a variable is on top of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, there is nothing called 'static memory' segment.

(1) Is in the DATA/BSS and it lives until the program is terminated.
(2) Is also in Data/BSS and it lives until the program is terminated.
(3) Is also in DATA/BSS and it lives until the program is terminated.

So if you wonder what are the differences?

(1) the scope (visibility) of the variable is throughout the program and other files can do a extern and get the variable and also this variable's data can be changed.

(2) the scope of this static variable is only within the function and life is through out the program and other files can't access this variable.

(3) Same as (1) as explained above, except that the value can't be changed as it's const.

All dynamically allocated (using calloc() or malloc() or other variants) only goes to Heap.